# Text book on real analysis for undergrad in statistics

Tags: textbooks, mathematical-analysis, statistics

May I get some recommendation on text book on real analysis for undergrad in statistics? 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a book that treats measure theory from a stats perspective, or a mathematical stats book that has a focus on real analysis? Also, is this a book for self-study to supplement for a student in a class, or will you be using it as the teacher, etc? It might be helpful to know the book's particular purpose.

Comment: The standard for real analysis is Walter Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis". I didn't get that as an undergraduate, and feel that I partly wasted a few decades by not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be more useful "for [an] undergrad in statistics"
than a text on pure real analysis? 
A review in an ASA journal says it is "user-friendly":

> Adams, Malcolm Ritchie, and Victor Guillemin.
>   *Measure theory and probability*. Boston: Birkhäuser, 1996.
>
> ---
>
> [image: cover]

---

> "…the text is user friendly to the topics it considers and should be very accessible…Instructors and students of statistical measure theoretic courses will appreciate the numerous informative exercises; helpful hints or solution outlines are given with many of the problems. All in all, the text should make a useful reference for professionals and students."—*The Journal of the American Statistical Association*